# Inconsistent values for getNumberFound() in Search API

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

I have a full-text search index with 42 documents like in the screenshot below:

[image: Documents list from AppEngine admin panel]

When I query the index for "" it returns all the 42 documents correctly (good), but when I use the limit and offset options in the query, the value returned for the total number of matches found (results.getNumberFound()) varies from time to time. It gives me different values for different offsets!! In short, making the same query just with different offset values gives a different value for results.getNumberFound() function!

NOTE: This happens *only* in production server after I deploy the app. In local server everything
works perfectly (i.e for the same query, the number of total hits found is the same regardless of the offset option value).

```
Query query =   Query.newBuilder()
                .setOptions(QueryOptions.newBuilder()
                .setLimit(limit)
                .setOffset(offset).build())
                .build(searchPhrase);

                Results<ScoredDocument> results = INDEX.search(query);
                LOG.warning(    "Phrase:'" + searchPhrase + 
                                "' limit:" + limit + 
                                " offset:" + offset + 
                                " num:" + results.getNumberFound());
```

Here's a screenshot of the log output:
[image: log]

So is there something wrong I'm doing or it's a bug in the Search API because the weird thing is that the issue only happens in the production server not the local one.

Answer (score 1):

The python docs say

`number_found`
Returns an approximate number of documents matching the query. QueryOptions defining post-processing of the search results. If the QueryOptions.number_found_accuracy parameter were set to 100, then number_found <= 100 is accurate.

Similiar api components in exist in Java.  From your code it appears you haven't set an accuracy.  See java QueryOptions https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/search/QueryOptions

Having said that I have seen many questions/discussions about lack of accuracy on the number of found results.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the answer. As far as I know, it defaults to 100 for the accuracy, and my total documents were only 42. I tried as you suggested to set the number_found_accuracy value. I set it to 999, but still, on production server it was showing very very bad approximations. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, this is working as intended (as Tim says).

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/search/QueryOptions.Builder#setNumberFoundAccuracy(int)

In its default state, the datastore scans the minimal set of data to fulfill the request.  The database provides a very rough estimate of match results by multiplying ID range with estimate of matching keys (#keys found that matched / #ids scanned during the query).

For small data sets, set the accuracy value higher (500 or 1000) and call it a day.  You can also improve the estimate by making sure key IDs are uniformly distributed and by fetching a higher limit each call (though if you don't need the data, just use the accuracy parameter).

This might not be applicable here but this is a general workaround for larger data sets:
Use num_accuracy == 1000.  When queries return an estimate of <1000, you can trust that.  When a query returns an estimate of >1000, perform your own estimate using a second query:
Include an extra numeric field with your data, which is a value of a discrete probabilistic event (e.g. #0s in a hash of some randomish data).  When you get a large estimate from the first query, repeat your query with the additional constraint (e.g. AND ZERO_COUNT == y), where y is chosen based on the first query's estimate to match <1000 entities, producing an exact count for the second query which you can accurately extrapolate.  Since you don't need the results of this data, you can set limit to 1 & num_accuracy == 1000.

Comment: Thanks Isaac, just sent you an email with the details.